# C Semaphore understanding

Tags: c

Let me explain better , i now that variable *contador needs semaphores ...

This exercise asked us to put semaphores so this two program works and *contador doesn't get over 200...

`while ((*contador)==MAX)`; was made by the University Teacher in one exam ,and is what i am trying to understand.

```
1. //program people enter
2. #define MAX 200 
3. int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
4. int *contador; 
5. 
6. int fd=shm_open("/contador",O_RDWR|O_CREAT,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR); 
7. 
8. int ret=ftruncate(fd,sizeof(int)); 
9. 
10. contador=mmap(0,sizeof(int),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0); 
11. 
12. while ((*contador)==MAX); 
13   sem_wait();
14. (*contador)++; 
15   sem_post();
16. } 




1. //program people get out
2. int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
3. int *contador; 
4. 
5. int fd=shm_open("/contador",O_RDWR|O_CREAT,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR); 
6. 
7. int ret=ftruncate(fd,sizeof(int)); 
8. 
9. contador=mmap(0,sizeof(int),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0); 
10. sem_wait();
11. (*contador)--; 
12  sem_post();
13. }
```

Answer (score 1):

well, as your code is written, `while ((*contador)==MAX);` should block infinitely… until the value of `*contador` gets equal to `MAX`.

Comment: Let me explain better this consists in two programs running at the same time with shared memory , one counts people that enter and the other people that get out . 

This one is the one that people enter , contador ++ , i now that it needs semaphore so it is writen one at the time .

MY question is , when this contador gets to 200 (== MAX) , it will cicle until the other program gets the value under 200 ?

Comment: wella actually rereading I assumed it was that problem (the "semaphore" in the title helped :-p). But still, it's blocking until you have MAX in your shared memory. So basically your program will end when and only when contador == MAX.

Comment: Hmm , if i understand  when it gets to 200 in shared memory , first program become a infinite loop until second decreases *contador. Is that it? Other question do you think that semaphores in sem_wait and sem_post are well done?

Comment: that's actually the other way around, the program you posted will stay blocked until the value in shared memory will be equal to `200`. I can't tell for both `sem_wait()`/`sem_post()`, as you did not give them. But try to stick to one question per post, if you've got another question, make a simple code example a bit of context and your other question!